# Por que me sale este error?

Tags: php

Me encuentro realizando una validacion en el Login y me sale este error

> Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioInfraestructura\php\validar.php on line 14
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioInfraestructura\php\validar.php:14
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioInfraestructura\php\validar.php on line 14

Alguien me puede colaborar, apenas estoy empezando con la programacion PHP y es la primer vez que me enfrento a esto. les dejo el codigo fuente.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    header('location: ../index.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $usuario = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    require('conexion.php');

    $consulta = $conexion -> prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Nombre_Usuario= :user AND Contrasena= :pass');
    $consulta ->execute(array(':user'=>$usuario, ':pass'=>$password));

    $resultado = $consulta -> fecth();
    if($resultado!==false){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header('location: index.php');
    }else{
        header('location: login.php');
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Que tiene este archivo **require('conexion.php');** ?

Comment: la conexion ...                                                                                               

<?php 

function conexion(){
 $servidor="localhost";
 $usuario="root";
 $contrasena="";
 $bd="inventario_infraestructura";

 $conexion=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$contrasena,$bd);

 return $conexion;
}

Comment: intenta poner en la linea despues del **require** esto: $conexion = conexion();

Comment: Ya no me aparece uno de los dos errores, sale el siguiente: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioInfraestructura\php\validar.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioInfraestructura\php\validar.php on line 14

Comment: Hasle un dump a conexion despues de la asignacion a ver que llega pk parece ke no es el tipo de dato que espera prepare

Comment: Disculpa, en esa parte me confundi...no entendi que debo hacer

Answer (score 0):

por que no intentas declarar la conexion a la base de datos despues de iniciar session? asi

```
session_start();
require('conexion.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    header('location: ../index.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $usuario = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];



    $consulta = $conexion -> prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Nombre_Usuario= :user AND Contrasena= :pass');
    $consulta ->execute(array(':user'=>$usuario, ':pass'=>$password));

    $resultado = $consulta -> fecth();
    if($resultado!==false){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header('location: index.php');
    }else{
        header('location: login.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo realize, y no obtuve resultado bueno.

Comment: podrias publicar el codigo de conexion para ver que pasa

Comment: <?php function conexion(){ $servidor="localhost"; $usuario="root"; $contrasena=""; $bd="inventario_infraestructura"; $conexion=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$contrasena,$bd); return $conexion; }

Comment: trata de hacer la conexion normal sin meterla en una function a ver que pasa

Comment: Has lo ke te recomienda @andy gibbs coje el cuerpo de tu función extraelo y ponlo en validar.php

Comment: Aun me sale este error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioInfraestructura\php\validar.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioInfraestructura\php\validar.php on line 14